# Ubuntu not finding executable in PATH

Tags: command-line, bash

I installed node and npm from sorce and created symbolic links to my `/usr/local/bin` folder.

npm works like, but trying to run node shows an annoying message instead of running the executable on `/usr/local/bin`

You can see the problem here:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-31-104:/usr/local/bin$ ls
f2py  node    npm
mvn   nodese  tensorboard
ubuntu@ip-172-31-31-104:/usr/local/bin$ npm -v 
2.14.20
ubuntu@ip-172-31-31-104:/usr/local/bin$ nodese -v
v4.4.1
ubuntu@ip-172-31-31-104:/usr/local/bin$ node -v
The program 'nodejs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install nodejs
ubuntu@ip-172-31-31-104:/usr/local/bin$ ./node
> 
(To exit, press ^C again or type .exit)
> 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-31-104:/usr/local/bin$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/bin
```

Even if `node` and `nodese` are the same symbolic link ubuntu first looks for `node` somewhere else and prints the `apt-get` message. How can I make Ubuntu look into $PATH first?

EDIT

this is the output of type -a

```
type -a node
node is aliased to `nodejs'
node is /usr/local/bin/node
node is /usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `type -a node`

Comment: I edited my question with the type -a output-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having issues with the naming of the link,node is aliased to nodejs, it tries to find (unsuccessfully) nodejs, while your link is named "node"... an easy way to fix this is to create a new symbolic link named nodejs instead of node in your bin folder

```
ln -s PATH_TO_YOUR_NODEJS /usr/bin/nodejs
```

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in the output of `type -a node`, you have an alias defined for node. Remove it:

```
unalias node
```

Look for the alias definition in your `.bashrc`, `.bash_aliases` and other such files, and remove it.

Comment: adding another symbolic link worked for me, but I guess this solution works too.